# How to disable editing registry by standard user in Win 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, uac

In the past a standard user in my Win 7 was not able to edit such registry key as `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules`.

But now I see that it's possible and I don't know why.

I've tried to change UAC, but it didn't help.

And I also can't resolve the issue by adding the `DisableRegistryTools` key under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`. As I can't add this key inside of the account of the standard user (don't have the requisite permissions).

So how to make standard user not be able to edit at least the `FirewallRules` key in the registry?

Please don't write about the group policy as it's missing in Win 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 Home Premium handles users in different way than Professional or Ultimate.

Test the settings like this.

1.) Control panel => User Accounts => Manage Accounts => Create New Account

2.) Enter the name of your test user and Choose "Standard user"

3.) Press "Create Account" button.

4.) Create a password for the test user.

5.) Log out and Log in with test

6.) regedit

[image]

[image]

Hint: you can change your current user privilege from Admin back to Standard User.

(*Referring to the chat below this answer*)

If all above have been done please check back to the registry as administrator and check whether user has permission on the registry key.

If user has write permission on the key simple remove his write permission.

Comment: Yes, the standard user was created the way you described. And in the past I was receiving the error window from your screenshot. But now I don't receive it. May it be related to the fact that I sometimes change the registry key I mentioned from Admin user?

Comment: Log in as admin user and check the permission on the registry key. If you see that user has write access on it than remove it.

Comment: yes, it helped, thank you! You may add this to your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Thank you. I glad to hear it helps. I modified my answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: maybe you also know why was I not temporary receiving the error window I was receiving in the past? What and when could changed so that I become able to re-write the record in the registry even in the account of the standard user?

Comment: If you enable audit in secpol.msc you can follow the changes on files. If it was not enabled you cannot tell when and how the permission changed.

Comment: The changes on files or in the registry? Or maybe you mean the registry is stored in a file?

Comment: "Audit Registry allows you to audit attempts to access registry objects.' - This link gives a better insight : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-registry